# I want to make an app which contains a Spinner and two ListView, I tried but I do not know what to do

Tags: android, database, listview, spinner

I want to make an app which contains a Spinner and two ListViews and when I click on item in Spinner it will open new ListView. I tryed with visibility and now I don’t know where it should be make ListViews.  think I have to create them in database but I don’t know how. How make two lists 
First list Samsung- s3, s4 ,s5, s6 endge
Second list Apple - 3g, 4, 5s ,6s

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.phone,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                                       int i, long l)
            {
                if (adapter.getItem(i)== "Samsung")
                {
                    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    listView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else if (adapter.getItem(i) == "Apple")
                {
                    listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    listView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In strings.xml for Spinner standing this

```
<string-array name="phone">
    <item>Samsung</item>
    <item>Apple</item>
</string-array
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GONE instead of INVISIBLE

```
listView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

INVISIBLE just make the component invisible. space occupied by the component is always occupied, just user can't see. Where GONE makes the component totally invisible from the user as well as free the space occupied by the component.